# React-native XCode build fails -> "Expected a type" (RTCNetworking.m)

Tags: javascript, xcode, react-native

I'm following the ["Getting Started" instructions for React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html), and getting this error at the build/run step:

```
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(connect:(NSURL *)URL socketID:(nonnull NSNumber *)socketID)
                                                 ^expected a type
```

Any clues?  As far as I know, all the previous steps were successful.

---

Actual steps, from the link I quoted:

**Requirements**

- OS X - Only OS X is currently supported
- Homebrew is the recommended way to install Watchman and Flow.
- Install Node.js 4.0 or newer.
- Install nvm with its setup instructions here. Then run `nvm install node && nvm alias default node`
- brew install watchman.

We recommend periodically running `brew update && brew upgrade` to keep your programs up-to-date.

**iOS Setup**

Xcode 6.3 or higher is required. It can be installed from the App Store.

**Quick start**

```
$ npm install -g react-native-cli
$ react-native init AwesomeProject
```

To run the iOS app:

```
$ cd AwesomeProject
Open ios/AwesomeProject.xcodeproj and hit run in Xcode.
```

Comment: Carumba, I'm still on Mavericks and this XCode 6.2.   Is this definitely the reason for the issue?  If it is, am I forced to upgrade at this point to proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

react-native specifies, and does indeed need, XCode 6.3 or greater for nullable support.